# gtag not sending click event data

Tags: javascript, jquery, gtag.js

Hopefully you can help me.  I'm trying to send event data to GA but my data isn't showing and I'm not sure what's causing the problem.  I'm not getting any errors in the console log.

```
 <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx-x">
 </script>
 <script>
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
   gtag('js', new Date());

   gtag('config', 'UA-xxx-x');
 </script>

 <script>
 $("#Btn1").click( function() {

    gtag('event', 'Click', {
        'send_to': 'UA-xxx-x',
        'event_category': 'Btn1',
        'event_label': 'test',
        'value': '1'
   });

 });

 $("#Btn2").click( function() {

    gtag('event', 'Click', {
        'send_to': 'UA-xxx-x',
        'event_category': 'Btn2',
        'event_label': 'test',
        'value': '2'
   });

 });
 </script>

 <a href="https://www.google.com" id="Btn1">Btn 1 Click</a>

 <a href="https://www.google.com" id="Btn2">Btn 2 Click</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common jquery error.

This doesn't work because you bind the "click event" before the id exists.

you should move html code before the js code where you define button behaviour